# ThrottleTime doesn't work correctly applied to an observable

Tags: angular, angular9

I am working on a project and I need to resend a forgotten username and I have to use throttleTime.

I have tried to applied after call the method but it is not working properly. Here is my code:

```
  resendLink() {
    this.recoverUsernameService
      .recoverUsername(this.email.value)
      .pipe(throttleTime(5000))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        //some actions
      });
  }
```

It doesn't return any console error or something but when I click again and again over the button the request is called all the times that the button is clicked(instead of avoid that).

Any idea?

Comment: Do you call resendLink everytime you click the button?

Comment: @Timon yes I call the method each time

Comment: well that is your problem. you subscribe each time.

Comment: @Timon how could I resolve it then if I have an observable?